# How to read strings from 2 columns into separate variables from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, multiple-columns

I have a text file that looks like this

```
fpath_1_a.txt fpath_1_b.txt
fpath_2_a.txt fpath_2_b.txt
fpath_3_a.txt fpath_3_b.txt
fpath_4_a.txt fpath_4_b.txt
```

The strings in the two columns are the paths to different files. I would like to read this text file such that I can loop through the individual rows, and in each iteration I have a string that contains path_a and path_b, so that I can read the corresponding files.
  How do I do this?

Comment: What is the separator? White space?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sep = " "
filename = "your text file name"
with open(filename) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for fname in line.split(sep):
            with open(fname) as gp:
                print gp.read()/* do something */
```